# Is it possible to run Git on an old Windows NT machine?

Tags: windows, git, windows-nt-4

I have a PC that needs to run Windows NT in order to maintain compatibility with some old test hardware.  I'd like to run Git on it for source control, but I can't find any information on Git's website about compatibility with NT.  Does anyone know if it's possible?

Comment: Even if it wasn't, you might succeed using it through Cygwin. You can also leverage network NFS or CIFS file mounts, if everything else fails. Good luck!